# git pull executed as wrong user. Unable to edit files now

Tags: git, permissions

I have pulled my git repo when I was "root". And, now am unable to edit my files when i come back to my normal account?

Apart from cloning the entire repository again, what is the other way of fixing this permission problem?

Or, is changing .git/FETCH_HEAD the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`# chown -R your_user git_repo_directory`

This will set you (username `youruser`) as the owner of the `git_repo_directory`.

`-R` tells to apply the new owner to files recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Us I understand, something like this can help you to fix the problem:

```
(root)find ./repofolder/ -name "*"  -uid 0 |xargs chown your_username:users
```

or just:

```
(root)chown -R your_username:users ./repofolder/
```